# Excelに組み込まれる Visual Studio Tools for office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel とは？

Tags: visual-studio

初心者です。
Visual Studio2017 にてExcel用アドインの開発を進めるにあたって、Excelに組み込まれる”Visual Studio Tools for office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel”　の概要について知っておきたいと思います。

・機能の概要は？
・常に読み込んでおかなければならないのか？
・作成したアドインの配布時にセットで組み込ませるようにする必要があるのか？

等、他にもこれは知っておくべきという情報がありましたらご教授いただきたいと
思います。よろしくお願いいたします。